# AttributeError: '...' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'

Tags: python, fastapi

Im trying to make a POST API function , but when i run my code, i have this error : AttributeError: 'Seller_brands' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'

Here`s the code :

```
class Seller_brands(BaseModel):
      
    __table__ = Table('seller', metadata,
            autoload=True,
            autoload_with=engine,
            schema='test')

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'primary_key': __table__.c.id_seller
    }

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True


@app.post("/create_seller_brand/")
def create_seller_brand(seller_brand:Seller_brands):
    session = Session()
    session.add(seller_brand)
    session.commit()
    return {"status": 200, "response": "Seller Brand inserted"}
```

Here`s the error :

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2599, in add
api_1  |     state = attributes.instance_state(instance)
api_1  | AttributeError: 'Seller_brands' object has no attribute '*sa_instance_state'
api_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise*
api_1  |     raise exception
api_1  | sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'api.main.Seller_brands' is not mapped

Comment: Seems that you are confusing between `pydantic` and `sqlalchemy` models.

Comment: I think soo , im already tryied to change BaseModel for Model , buti i got another error : fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError: Invalid args for response field! Hint: check that <class 'api.main.Seller_brands'> is a valid pydantic field type

Comment: Try to look at FastApi documentation a bit or check tutorials on the web : you need an SQL Alchemy model for your data persistence and pydantic model for schema validation for the HTTP request and response body. These are two different things

Comment: The view function needs to have a pydantic model to map the request onto - , so `seller_brand` needs to be a pydantic model. [SQLModel is the combination of pydantic and SQLAlchemy](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/) by the author of FastAPI